# Generate a dynamic ListView

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

I am following the example http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-dynamic.html , but my problem is that it does not render the page at all, i only se a white page. I do not know what are the problem, even i've changed the `page.page()` to `page.trigger('create')`, and also try the `content.find(":jqmData(role=listview)").listview('refresh')` but nothing at all. The thing is i do not have an error in the console, so i do not know what i am doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
$(document).bind("pagebeforechange", function(e, data) {
    console.log('[binding][pagebeforechange]');
    if( typeof data.toPage === "string") {
        var u = $.mobile.path.parseUrl(data.toPage);
        if(u.hash.search(/^#watch/) !== -1) {
            console.log('[binding] setWatch');
            var id = u.hash.replace(/.*id=/, "");
            e.preventDefault();
            setWatch(u, id);
        } else if(u.hash.search(/^#playlist/) !== -1) {
            console.log('[binding] setPlaylist');
            //Bind the change page event, and if it is playlist page, call setPlaylist
            playlistId = u.hash.replace(/.*id=/, "");
            e.preventDefault();
            setPlaylist(u);
        }
    }
});

function setPlaylist(urlObj) {
    console.log('[setPlaylist]');
    var page = $('#playlist');
    var content = $('#playlistContent');
    var html = getListHtml(playlistId); //Here a get the complete list code
    content.empty();
    content.html(html);
    console.log('[setPlaylist] before trigger');
    page.trigger('create');
    //page.page();
    //content.find(":jqmData(role=listview)").listview('refresh');
    page.listview();

    var options = {};
    options.reloadPage = true;
    options.dataUrl = urlObj.href;
    options.transition = "slide";
    $.mobile.changePage(page, options);
    console.log('[setPlaylist] changepage');
    location.hash = urlObj.hash;
}
```

So if you have any idea of what i am doing wrong, please let me know.

Thanks!!

Edit:

If i use `content.find(":jqmData(role=listview)").listview('refresh')` it show the next error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery16401444779944140464'
>   of undefined

And it seem that the `pagebeforechange` is it fire twice. Really i did not know what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Could you link to a demo page? Maybe http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Today is a very bad day so just use this: http://touch.hollybyte.com/index.html
Maybe tomorrow i upload to jsfiddle or something but today it is imposible.

Comment: With jQM you don't use document.ready http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/page-scripting.html also I get this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery16408813936458900571' of undefined"

Comment: I also get a 403 response: http://repo.eu-w1.hollybyte.com/undefined

Comment: Also could you move the /js/smartphone.js after you have added the jQM lib?

Comment: fist i have to xplain that mess up code, xD. I also have tried with bindind the "pageinit" event, but i does not work, so i left. Don't mind the videoJS, because i am trying to let my boss that we don't need it, but for the time been, just ignore it. Your 403 response is because you tried to click "Level 1", but the page does not change nor the new list is shown, but the url does, so when you tried to click on a video next, you got that response. If you simple click on a video first, you will not have that repsonse. I know it is a really bad code and i will cleaned up, i promise.

Comment: The important thing is, if you click on "Level 1", it have to generate a dinamic list, an show the new list. Right now, the change page does nothing. Tomorrow i'll use jsFidle with a fairly clean code so you can test it if you want. Thanks for helping me

Comment: Done. /js/smparphone.js is after JQM lib. Still nothing.

Comment: As promise here is the fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/Tolke/2u9L6/3/

Comment: in video.js I get this error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" Also jQM uses jQuery 1.6.4 but you're using .on() which is for 1.7 http://jsfiddle.net/2u9L6/7/

Comment: don't worry just now i figure out the error, a DAMM </div> that was missing, believe me, all the week for this error.. I nearly kill myself when i discover it. Thank's for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

The error was a missing , so jqm cannot find the page to change to, and all the error was for that. Thank you very much Emre for helping me.

Comment: Where is there a missing ','?